# Child method compatible with parent method in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, inheritance, overriding, php-5.4

Recently, I've started suffering with a 5.4 PHP Server because of the child/parent method comparison. I do understand the error, but I don't understand the concept. 
Why is PHP implementing this? Is the following snap-code a bad behavior? Why is it a bad behavior? How to "correctly" build a "shortcut-method" in child classes now that the signature must be compatible?

```
Class File {
      public function validate($exts, $maxSize){
          // Validate if this->flie is valid according to extension and size.
      }

}

Class Image extends File {
      public function validate($maxSize){
         $exts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");
         return parent::validate($exts, $maxSize);
      }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
Class File {
      public function validate($maxSize, $exts){
          // if !is_array || empty $exts throw exception
          // Validate if this->file is valid according to extension and size.
      }

}

Class Image extends File {
      public function validate($maxSize, $exts=array()){
         $exts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");
         return parent::validate($maxSize, $exts);
      }    
}
```